# Getting survey list settings (questions, possible answers) via REST

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, survey-list, survey

I need to custom render the survey on the client side so I need to be able to get it's settings via a REST (or web service) call. 
I tried calling Web/Lists(listguid)/Fields and I get all the fields including the survey questions, but I don't see how to distinguish "question" fields from all other fields - there is no special type or flag saying that this field is a question. 
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Any one know a resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to get the list of questions from a Survey List via REST API

You could specify [SPField.CanBeDeleted property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.canbedeleted.aspx) in filter expression to get the list of *questions* from a Survey List:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Survey')/fields?$filter=(CanBeDeleted eq true)
```

The following endpoint returns all the *answers* from a Survey list:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Survey')/items
```

Comment: hello can i add survey list item using rest?